# How to make this particular layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, styles, material-design

[image: How can I make this layout?]
Hey everyone I am trying to make a new app and I found this layout on the internet. Can please anyone help me or tell me how to make this layout.

Comment: You see how to create layout here -> https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/ and this -> https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="123" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvTop"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="45446445446" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvTop"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="45446445446" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTop2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="123" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvTop2"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="45446445446" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvTop2"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="45446445446" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]